# Centering is thrown off by scrollbar width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm trying to center the content of two `<div>`s using flexbox. I have taken a look to the following thread:
[scrolling flex container does not fit centered items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599431/scrolling-flex-container-does-not-fit-centered-items)

The content of the `<div>`s is a table with fixed width and I set the flex-grow to none. The problem is that the space taken by the scrollbar of the second div is also considered while aligning.

Here a simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/boc39Lsa/2/

```css
#container {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
}
.item {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 0;
}


.item:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
.item:last-child {
    margin-right:auto;
}

.bigContent{
  height: 1000px;
}

.scroll{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
      <table width="500px">
        <tr><td>Header</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="item scroll">
      <div class="bigContent">
         <table width="500px">
            <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
         </table>
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the scrollbar adds to an element's width, and as the width of a scrollbar differs between browsers, there is no immediate property to use to avoid this behavior.

The simplest solution that cross my mind is to use an initial `flex-basis` of 500px and set the `table` to be 100% wide

Stack snippet

```css
#container {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-basis: 500px;
}

.item:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
.item:last-child {
    margin-right:auto;
}

.bigContent{
  height: 1000px;
}

.scroll{
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
      <table width="100%">
        <tr><td>Header</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="item scroll">
      <div class="bigContent">
         <table width="100%">
            <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
         </table>
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

To make the content in the center, you just need to set the alignment inside the container to center, like

```
text-align: center;
```

```css
#container {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
}
.item {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 0;
}


.item:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
.item:last-child {
    margin-right:auto;
}

.bigContent{
  height: 1000px;
}

.scroll{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
      <table width="500px">
        <tr><td>Header</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="item scroll">
      <div class="bigContent">
         <table width="500px">
            <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
         </table>
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not the text that should be centered, it is the elements. And btw, I didn't down vote.